# Rails the alternative plan of rescue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I read some of article said rails `rescue` will lead performance problem. 
For example

```
a = Course.where(id: 20).first #better
a = Course.find(20) rescue nil #worse
```

Then how do I rewrite the following code in best way

```
parent_section = parent_section.section rescue nil
```

I've tried this

```
parent_section = parent_section.section if parent_section.section.present?
```

It works fine, but I thought it's too long and mess.
Is there a better way to achieve that?

### Update

If the code is

```
parent_section_id = parent_section.section.id rescue nil
```

How do I rewrite it?

Comment: why do you need rescue? why does calling `section` raise an exception? If this is just an Active Record association, then it shouldn't raise any exception, and will just return nil naturally if there isn't a section present. You should be able to replace your code with `parent_section = parent_section.section`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I test it and `parent_section = parent_section.section` can work, I should modify my question.

Comment: I'll make it into an answer :)

Comment: BTW, although raising and catching exceptions adds some overhead, it's most likely not your bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is just an Active Record association, then it shouldn't raise any exception when you call `section` on your `parent_section`. It will just return nil naturally if there isn't a section present, so you won't need the `rescue` at all. You should be able to replace your code with:

```
parent_section = parent_section.section
```

If you want to call something on the result (eg id) then you can use `try` - which will only call the method named if the thing is not nil  eg:

```
parent_section_id = parent_section.section.try(:id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my question.

Comment: ok, for future reference... you shouldn't do that... because the comments now make no sense. You should add an "EDIT" or "UPDATE" section after your original question :)

Comment: Ok I got it, I will do that

Comment: Thanks, great help :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the `id` of the section that could be `nil` you could look at using `try` on it which will also return `nil`

`parent_section_id = parent_section.section.try(:id)`